# Optimize mysql query involving millions of rows

Tags: mysql

I have, in a project, a database with two big tables, "terminosnoticia" have 400 Million rows and "noticia" 3 Million. I have one query I want to make lighter (it spend from 10s to 400s):

```
    SELECT noticia_id, termino_id
      FROM noticia 
      LEFT JOIN terminosnoticia on terminosnoticia.noticia_id=noticia.id AND termino_id IN (7818,12345) 
     WHERE noticia.fecha BETWEEN '2016-09-16 00:00' AND '2016-09-16 10:00' 
       AND noticia_id is not null AND termino_id is not null;`
```

The only viable solution I have to explore is to denormalize the database to include the 'fecha' field in the big table, but, this will multiply the index sizes.

Explain plan:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref                                     | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | terminosnoticia | ref    | noticia_id,termino_id | termino_id | 4       | const                                   | 58480 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | noticia         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fecha         | PRIMARY    | 4       | db_resumenes.terminosnoticia.noticia_id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Changing the query and creating the index as suggested, the explain plan is now:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                             | key                 | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T     | ref    | noticia_id,termino_id,terminosnoticia_cpx | terminosnoticia_cpx | 4       | const                     | 60600 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | N     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fecha                             | PRIMARY             | 4       | db_resumenes.T.noticia_id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

But the execution time does not vary too much...

Any idea?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x WHERE x IS NOT NULL` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: Is `noticia_id` an index column in both tables?

Comment: noticia_id have index in terminosnoticia and noticia.id is primary

Comment: Note that questions about query performance ALWAYS require as a minimum, CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Strawberry LEFT JOIN x WHERE x IS NOT NULL is not the same as INNER JOIN in terms of performance. Depending on the data and the query you can see huge differences.

Comment: Can you post CREATE TABLE for both tables?

Comment: @verhie I think you've rather missed the point of my comment - although, to be fair, I could have been more explicit - as per DRapp's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Strawberry pointed out, by having an "AND" in your where clause for NOT NULL 
is the same as a regular INNER JOIN and can be reduced to.

```
 SELECT 
       N.id as noticia_id, 
       T.termino_id
   FROM 
      noticia N  USING INDEX (fecha)
         JOIN terminosnoticia T
            on N.id = T.noticia_id
            AND T.termino_id IN (7818,12345) 
   WHERE 
      N.fecha BETWEEN '2016-09-16 00:00' AND '2016-09-16 10:00'
```

Now, that said and aliases applied, I would suggest the following covering indexes as

```
table           index
Noticia         ( fecha, id )
terminosnoticia ( noticia_id, termino_id )
```

This way the query can get all the results directly from the indexes and not have to go to the raw data pages to qualify the other fields.

Comment: Thank you, but creating the index and executing the query in this way does not change too much the time of the query because mysql selected the primary key of noticias instead the fecha key. I modified the query adding "USING INDEX (fecha)" near "noticia N" and this do the trick... The query now is much faster.
I select this as the correct answer (please, add the USING INDEX in te  query if you can).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `noticia_id` is `noticia`'s primary key, I would add the following indexes:

```
create index noticia_fecha_idx on noticia(fecha);
create index terminosnoticia_id_noticia_idx on terminosnoticia(noticia_id);
```

And try your queries again.

Do include the current execution plan of your query. It might help on helping you figuring this one out.

Comment: Added execution plan in the question... Every field have its index

Comment: Do you have an index on (noticia_id, termino_id) on `terminosnoticia` table? Are you using `terminosnoticia` to perform a full text search?

Comment: Do you mean create a composite index? 
create index terminosnoticia_cpx on terminosnoticia (noticia_id,termino_id)
?

Comment: Yes, but I would do it: `(termino_id, noticia_id)`.

Comment: I'll try in the development environment... I'm afraid about the amount of time the index can take to be created.
Thxs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tbl1.noticia_id, tbl1.termino_id FROM
( SELECT FROM terminosnoticia WHERE
terminosnoticia.termino_id IN (7818,12345) 
AND terminosnoticia.noticia_id is not null 
) tbl1 INNER JOIN 
( SELECT id FROM noticia 
  WHERE noticia.fecha
  BETWEEN '2016-09-16 00:00' AND '2016-09-16 10:00'
) tbl2 ON tbl1.id=tbl2.noticia.id
```

Comment: Since MySQL is going to materialize the inline views, it's hard to fathom how this will give better performance. Given the overhead for materializing the derived tables, and then the outer query running against the contents of those table... and older versions of MySQL, the derived tables are never indexed. When you say "try this", can you give some rationale why OP should do that?

Answer (score 0):

We're assuming that the `noticia_id` and `termino_id` are columns in `terminosnoticia` table.  (We wouldn't have to guess, if all of the column references were *qualified* with the table name or a short table alias.)

Why is this an outer join? The predicates in the WHERE clause are going to exclude rows with NULL values for columns from `terminosnoticia`. That's going to negate the "outerness" of the join.

And if we write this as an inner join, those predicates in the WHERE clause are redundant. We already know that `noticia_id` won't be NULL (if it satisfies the equality predicate in the ON clause). Same for `termino_id`, that won't be NULL if it's equal to a value in the IN list.

I believe this query will return an equivalent result:

```
  SELECT t.noticia_id
       , t.termino_id
    FROM noticia n
    JOIN terminosnoticia t
      ON t.noticia_id = n.id
     AND t.termino_id IN (7818,12345)
   WHERE n.fecha BETWEEN '2016-09-16 00:00' AND '2016-09-16 10:00'
```

What's left now is figuring out if there's any implicit datatype conversions.

We don't see the datatype of `termino_id`. So we don't know if that's defined as numeric. It's bad news if it's not, since MySQL will have to perform a conversion to numeric, for every row in the table, so it can do the comparison to the numeric literals.

We don't see the datatypes of the `noticia_id`, and whether that matches the datatype of the column it's being compared to, the `id` column from `noticia` table.

We also don't see the datatype of `fecha`. Based on the string literals in the between predicate, it looks like it's probably a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. But that's just a guess. We don't know, since we don't have a table definition available to us.

Once we have verified that there aren't any implicit datatype conversions that are going to bite us...

For the query with the inner join (as above), the best shot at reasonable performance will likely be with MySQL making effective use of *covering indexes*. (A *covering index* allows MySQL to satisfy the query directly from from the index blocks, without needing to lookup pages in the underlying table.)

As DRApp's answer already states, the best candidates for covering indexes, for this particular query, would be:

```
 ... ON noticia (fecha, id)
 ... ON terminosnoticia (noticia_id, termino_id)
```

An index that has those same leading columns in that same order would also be suitable, and would render these indexes redundant.

The addition of these indexes will render other indexes redundant.

The first index would be redundant with `... ON noticia (fecha)`. Assuming the index isn't enforcing a UNIQUE constraint, it could be dropped. Any query making effective use of that index could use the new index, since `fecha` is the leading column in the new index.

Similarly, an index `... ON terminosnoticia (noticia_id)` would be redundant. Again, assuming it's not a unique index, enforcing a UNIQUE constraint, that index could be dropped as well.